How jamming resistant is UWB communication?
What is the effective range of UWB jamming (i.e., up to what distance around a jammer is a UWB communication impossible?). Is UWB jamming currently usual in Ukraine?
The aim is to get example configurations of, or an explained equation with parameters:

power of emitter and of jammer

type of system

noise margin

frequency ranges
And the resulting range of the jammer


I am especially interested in short range jamming up to 200 m.


What is the effective range of UWB jamming (i.e. up to what distance around a jammer is a UWB communication impossible?)

The questions you ask can't be answered without knowing at the very least power of emitter and jammer, type of system, noise margin and frequency ranges. "UWB" defines none of this.

Is UWB jamming currently usual in Ukraine?

I'm not even sure which UWB systems you are expecting to operate in a war zone.
